# SendKeys is messing with my NumLock key via VBA code in Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, sendkeys

I have the following code for an Access form. It appears as if the `SendKeys` is messing with my <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key by toggling it on and off as I open and close the form.

For perfectly valid reasons which I don't want to get into, I really do not want to completely hide the ribbon (I want the pull down menus still accessible) so the `DoCmd.ShowToolbar` command is not my preferred way of doing it.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can modify the code below to accomplish what I want using the `SendKeys` command?

Using Access 2007 so the command

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
```

is not available to me.

By the way, database will be distributed so solution must be contained within database.

```
Private Sub Form_Close()

' Unhide navigation pane
    DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
    DoCmd.Maximize

' Maximize the ribbon
RibbonState = (CommandBars("Ribbon").Controls(1).Height < 75)

Select Case RibbonState
    Case True
        SendKeys "^{F1}", True
    Case False
        'Do nothing, already maximized
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
' Hide navigation pane
    DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
    DoCmd.Minimize
Debug.Print Application.CommandBars.Item("Ribbon").Height
' Minimize ribbon
RibbonState = (CommandBars("Ribbon").Controls(1).Height < 100)

Select Case RibbonState
    Case True
        'Do nothing, already minimized
    Case False
            SendKeys "^{F1}", False
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179987/ (KB179987). This seems to be a known bug, but I can't test right now what exactly prevents it from happening.

Comment: I tried adding DoEvents immediately after both SendKeys commands but it changed nothing. I was very confused as to how to use the DoEvents function. Can one of the VBA gurus help me modify this code to make it work?

Answer (score 21):

It's a bug in Microsoft VBA. But there is a workaround.

Use <kbd>F8</kbd> to run through the macro and find where it turns it off. It's usually after a `SendKeys`.

Then add an
    `Sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}", True` after the line to reverse the effect.

If you can't find it, just add it at the end and when it finishes, it will go back. Hopefully, if you add it during the show/hide process, it will work.

Answer (score 8):

This is caused  by :

```
Sendkeys "any key", False
```

Instead of `False` as second parameter, use `True`.

Comment: Still occurs for me with `True` set.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue and I found solution on some vba forum. Instead of buggy Sendkeys you can simulate kyes like this.

```
    Option Explicit
'//WIN32API Declare
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

'//WIN32API Constant

Public Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = &H1
Public Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Public Const VK_CONTROL = &H11
Public Const VK_SHIFT = &H10
Public Const VK_F6 = &H75

Public Function PreviousTab()
    keybd_event VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_F6, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_F6, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Function
```

Other keys can be found here [vba forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?277384-VB-Key-COnsts)
This "previousTab" function just send Control+Shift+F6 key.

Answer (score 7):

When you do a final sendKeys command in your code, adding in {NUMLOCK} to the statement may do the trick, as noted by RodB and iceBird76. But this is not a good coding practice, and here is why: if anything is different from one time to the next when you run the macro, it may or may not work.  I know this because I was experiencing a similar issue myself. When I would do a sendKeys command at the end of my program, sometimes the Num Lock would stay on, but other times it would stay off, just depending on certain variables in my spreadsheet (regardless of whether or not I included {NUMLOCK} in my last SendKeys statement).
I won't get into the details of my own variables, but the point is that to build a program/macro that will keep your Num Lock on consistently, you need to FIRST TEST TO SEE IF THE NUM LOCK IS ON OR OFF, then execute code based upon the present condition.

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Private Const kNumlock = 144

Public Function NumLock() As Boolean
    NumLock = KeyState(kNumlock)
    If (NumLock = True) Then
        MsgBox ("Num lock was off. Will turn back on now...")
        SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
    Else: MsgBox ("Num Lock stayed on")
    End If
End Function

Private Function KeyState(lKey As Long) As Boolean
    KeyState = CBool(GetKeyState(lKey))
End Function


Sub myMainMethod()
    'do a function here that includes .SendKeys
    Call NumLock
End Sub
```

This sample program will give you a confirmation message as to whether the Num Lock is on or off, and turn it on if it is off.

Answer (score 7):

The SendKeys() function that is built-in VBA has really a side effect that causes NumLock to be deactivated. But you can use a workaround and call another implementation of the same function that is a part of WSCRIPT component (a part of Windows operating system). The following sample code shows, how a reference to this component can be made and then its method called:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^g", True
```

This way, you get the same functionality (calling Ctrl-G keyboard shortcut in the example), but there is no issue with NumLock in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Right after your SendKeys statement add these 2 lines:

```
DoEvents
SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}"
```

Answer (score 3):

This line caused my problem:

```
Application.SendKeys "%s"
```

SOLVED by changing to this:

```
Application.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}%s"
```

There's no difference between adding `{NUMLOCK}` at the beginning or end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

in my case application.senkeys method was creating this problem. so I used

```
with shell
.sendkeys "{}"
End with
```

Instead of

```
with shell
Application.sendkeys ("{}")
End with
```

Answer (score 1):

64bit VBA version

```
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
   Private Const VK_NUMLOCK = &H90

   If GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) = 0 Then
      SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
   End If
```

You could also check the return value from GetKeyState() before using SendKeys() and restore it by either executing SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}" or not when finished.

Answer (score 0):

`SendKeys "^{HOME}", True` was turning off the <kbd>num lock</kbd> so I just repeated the command and it turns it back on again:

```
SendKeys "^{HOME}", True
SendKeys "^{HOME}", True
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many solutions. The most solid seems to be on the link below. Paste it to a Module.

http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0046.htm

Comment: Please ["add context around the link"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an adaptation of `SendETHToThisAddress's` answer which worked for me, as their answer did not work (fully.). . .

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Private Const NumlockKey = 144

Public Function Reset_NumLock() As Boolean
    Reset_NumLock = KeyState(NumlockKey)
    If (Reset_NumLock = False) Then 'Checking for True gave incorrect results
      ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
      ' Modified This - removed MsgBox too '
      ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''  
        With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
          .SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
        End With
    Else
      Debug.Print "Num Lock was on!  WOOT!"
    End If
End Function

Private Function KeyState(lKey As Long) As Boolean
    KeyState = CBool(GetKeyState(lKey))
End Function
```

> In my instance of Windows, the `KeyState` had to be `False` in order
> to accurately depict whether the Numlock key was off.  Additionally,
> if I used `Application.SendKeys`, it *NEVER* saw the state change
> correctly and would always alternate the status of my numlock vs *keep
> it on* as what appears to be the goal of their function (meaning - if
> I turned it on, this would turn it off.  If I turned it off, this
> would turn it on. . .).
>
> Sending 2x `{Numlock}` also created a problem where it never saw the
> numlock turned ON, even though it was!  (I believe this was due to it
> being in a specific state/condition when first attempt was made -
> still - I did not care for this.)
>
> Additionally, their answer does not specify whether they are using
> `Application.SendKeys` or another adaptation of it, so I find it
> rather ambiguous, and prefer to unequivocally state what kind of
> adaptation I'm using.  With the modified code below - I had 100%
> success rate with 200 tries (give or take, rapid fire, toggling the
> numlock key roughly every other interval). . .
>
> That said - the only way to prevent the `GetKeyState` function to
> properly see my Numlock status was to NOT use `Excel's SendKeys` but
> instead use `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` method.
>
> Otherwise, the core of this answer is very close to what
> `SendETHToThisAddress` proposed, as at the core, I ultimately wanted a
> way to ensure that Numlock was always on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I've been annoyed by this bug for years and it still happens a decade later. I just found an easy workaround. I don't really know how it works, but it does and I want others who find this thread to try it out, so here it goes:

Forget about checking NumLock status and the API and everything else. Just use your sendkeys command as you intended and add the following after the last sendkeys:

```
DoEvents
Sendkeys "^", True
```

I found that the PtrSafe GetKeyState function only returned the status correctly when the key was actually pressed, and not when the state was changed as a result of the VBA bug. DoEvents makes the bug go off, and then you send another key (I chose control because it had no effect on my application at all) and that triggers another instance of the bug, effectively undoing the first one.

During tests I noticed that CapsLock is also affected by this bug and it gets restored as well when forcing the bug once again.

I am aware that this is not a technical solution, but it's a very practical one that has consistently worked and effectively solved the problem for me. I'm sure others will find an explanation, and I will be very happy if at least one person finds this helpful.