# How to automatically expand drop-down validation list

Tags: excel, vba, validation, dropdown

Is there any alternative to`SendKeys` to expand drop-down validation list automatically? I would like to expand drop-down validation list after clicking on a cell. The focus of my question is entirely on how to avoid `SendKeys` method.

Here is a properly working solution using `SendKeys`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If HasValidation(Target) Then
        SendKeys "%{DOWN}"
        SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True 'Workaround for Numlock turn off bug
    End If
End Sub

Function HasValidation(MyCell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim t: t = Null
    On Error Resume Next
    t = MyCell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0
    HasValidation = Not IsNull(t)
End Function
```

Related links:
`HasValidation` function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31346246/1903793
`NumLock` bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29551913/1903793

The code above works smoothly without a hitch. I am just biased against`SendKeys` for widely reported issues. I suspect that incorporating this solution into larger code might cause unexpected behavior in the future which might be hard to capture.

Comment: Do you experience issues with this right now? Because I actually think this is quite nice :)

Comment: @AlexdeJong No, not any at all. It works smoothly. It's just a matter of caution. I am biased to use SendKeys. I suspect it may lead to issues in the future that will be hard to trap.

Answer (score -1):

Your definition of what you wish to achieve leaves a few questions to be answered but perhaps the code below will put you on the right path.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const Trigger As String = "A3:B4"               ' modify to suit
    Const ValCell As String = "H3"                  ' modify as required

    Dim ValType As Long

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(Trigger)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range(ValCell).Activate

        On Error Resume Next
        ValType = ActiveCell.Validation.Type
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ValType = 3 Then SendKeys "%{DOWN}"

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The above procedure monitors the *Trigger* range A3:B4, which you can adjust to what you need. If one of the cells in this range (it could be a single cell range) is clicked the dropdown in the cell having the validation, defined as *ValCell*, expands, provided it exists. The code achieves this by activating the `CellVal` cell.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is useless. My question is focused on how to avoid `SendKeys` and not on how to replace `HasValidation` function. You have not proposed replacement for`SendKeys "%{DOWN}"`. On the contrary, you have used that.

Comment: Go back to your question and modify it to say what you want. My answer expands the validation drop-down "when a cell is clicked".  If this must be accomplished using particular code about which you seem to know nothing except that it shouldn't contain `SendKeys` you owe an explanation why that should be a requirement.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I thought I was clear. I refined my question. Thank you! Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: The "widely reported issues" amount to the fact that `SendKeys` must be used in a controlled environment and you don't want to make the effort to control yours. Fair enough, but why can't you expand the drop-down by clicking the arrow it has for that purpose? Which cell you want clicked to expand it? How many of them are there on your sheet?