# Do a basic double click on a cell using VBA ,other than using SendKeys "{F2}"

Tags: excel, vba

When you are working in Excel and double click on a cell,
it selects the cells and gives you a blinking cursor within the cell to enter values or a formula.
I tried the below code, It works ,**But** it turns off `Num Lock` on my keyboard (I do not know why) .

```
SendKeys "{F2}"
```

Appreciate for yours comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in VBA: [SendKeys is messing with my NumLock key via VBA code in Access form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977933/sendkeys-is-messing-with-my-numlock-key-via-vba-code-in-access-form)

To workaround send NumLock:

```
SendKeys "{F2}"
SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
```

Comment: It works right now 